# C# DataTable Linq select distinct values where column equals 'x'

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Datatable (Groups) designed like so

ColumnA|ColumnB

X|Apple

Y|Purple

X|Apple

X|Mango

I basically want to select from columna where it's X and get the disinct from ColumnB

This is what I have

```
 var names = (from DataRow dr in Groups.Rows
                 orderby (string)dr["ColumnB"]
                 select (string)dr["ColumnB"]).Distinct();
```

This will give me distinct but it gives me Purple, and i dont want purple.

Thanks!

Comment: you should add a `where` block

Answer (score 8):

```
var names = (from DataRow dr in Groups.Rows
                 where dr["ColumnA"] == "X"
                 orderby (string)dr["ColumnB"]
                 select (string)dr["ColumnB"]).Distinct();
```

Comment: Sarwar i'm getting ErrorCannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. `=` should be replaced with `==`. I've updated my answer

Comment: where (string)dr["ColumnA"] == "X" that fixed it

Answer (score 3):

```
DataTable dt2 = dt1.Select("ColumnA = 'X'").CopyToDataTable().DefaultView.ToTable(true, "ColumnB");
```

So here we are selecting only the rows of data that you want, only rows where columnA is X.  Then we choose only to see columnB, but with unique values only. Doing it in this order, you'll receive another datatable to play with.  It'll only contain 1 column, columnB, and it'll only have unique/distinct values.

Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

If your return has more than one value and you want to Distinct the whole set by just one of the values you should use a custom [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx).

```
var names = (from DataRow dr in Groups.Rows
             where (string)dr["ColumnA"] == "X"
             orderby (string)dr["ColumnB"]
             select new { 
                ColumnA = (string)dr["ColumnA"], 
                ColumnB = (string)dr["ColumnB"]
            }).Distinct(new MyCustomEqualityComparer());
```

**edit:** to include where clause

**edit2:** changed to custom IEqualityComparer

Comment: No, you can not. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx

Comment: That's true. I didn't check the code before posting. What he can do is in fact use a custom IEqualityComparer if he just wants to distinct by one of the many returned values. I updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out @recursive